# How to check if an enum flag is raised alongside with another enum?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, flags

I have the following enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Permissions
{
    None = 0x0000,
    All = 0xFFFF
}
```

If either None or All are raised, no other flag should be raised.
How do I check if either None or All are raised and nothing else?

Comment: You are not using the `Flags` attribute correctly.  The attribute is meant for enums that are implemented as bitmasks, and if your enum were a bitmask, then you wouldn't need to ask this question since `None` would be `0` and `All` would be `0xFFFF`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute

Comment: If use used Flags correctly then None would have mask 0000...0 and All would have mask 1111...1, which means that `All` corresponds to all flags set and `None` to none flags set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a flags enum, `None` should be zero, and `All` should be the cumulative bitwise sum. This makes the maths pretty easy, then:

```
if(value == Permissions.None || value == Permissions.All) {...}
```

maybe written as a `switch` if you prefer...

However, in the *general* case, you can test for a complete flags match (against any number of bits) with:

```
if((value & wanted) == wanted) {...}
```

and to test for any overlap (i.e. any common bits - `wanted` needs to be non-zero):

```
if((value & wanted) != 0) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a completely foreign concept to me but a very cool feature of the language. Thanks for the clarification. Never did much AND'ing or OR'ing in Java :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(value|Permissions.None)==Permissions.None;
```

This can check Permissions.None is raised. The rest can be done in the same manner.